# Sometimes Not getting model values on partial pages in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

When we pass consecutive long string of same character of 256 length to view from controller using model variable, we are not getting that value on partial view pages. In other cases like small string or consecutive long string of different character of 256 length,  we are able to get that value on partial view pages.

If somebody can help please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the view code?